# Asp.net core mvc ajax post to controller with multiple parameters return bad request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have my controller action methods as follows,

```
public class UserController : BaseController<UserController>
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Assignment(Guid id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Assignment(Guid id, [FromBody] List<UserViewModel> assignees)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The ajax method in `Assignment.cshtml` page

```
$("#btn-save").click(function () {
    var url = "/User/Assignment/@Model.SelectedUser.Id";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ assignees: assignmentPage.SelectedUsers })
    });
});
```

So this builds a url like;

> `http://localhost:8800/User/Assignment/f474fd0c-69cf-47eb-7281-08d6536da99f`

This is the only route configuration in my `Startup.cs`.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

I never hit to Assignment **post** action, server returns **400**, I've searched and couldn't find yet, how am I supposed to configure my route for an action like this?

Comment: error 400 means bad request. Other than, everything seems ok. What's the implementation of `BaseController<>`? What else do you have in startup? and what's your skd's version? give more information.

Comment: `BaseController` has only two injected properties for derived ones. I don't want to fill the whole Startup code irrelevantly, so what part of `Startup` you need? sdk is indicated in tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem for my case is I am using [AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.autovalidateantiforgerytokenattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.1) configuration

```
services.AddMvc(options =>{
    // Automatically add antiforgery token valdaiton to all post actions.
    options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
}
```

So, ajax post has not any request verification token with itself, lack of this token server returns bad request.

To overcome this, I followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.1#javascript), so my final working code as,

**Assignment.cshtml**

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf
@functions
{
    public string GetAntiXsrfRequestToken() => Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(Context).RequestToken;
}
<input type="hidden" id="RequestVerificationToken" name="RequestVerificationToken" 
       value="@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btn-saveinspectors").click(function () {
        var url = "/Audit/Assignment/@Model.SelectedUser.Id";
        var assignees = JSON.stringify(assignmentPage.SelectedUsers);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('#RequestVerificationToken').val());
            },
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: assignees,
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
}
```

**Note:** This is my case that there is **not** any form inside my page where a request verification token is generated automatically. If you have a form in your page where you make an ajax request then you can follow [this post](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/handle-ajax-requests-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/)

Answer (score 1):

The data you are sending to your server is *invalid*. It's expecting a JSON array, but you're sending it a JSON object with a single property that itself is an array. You receive a 400 status-code due to the fact that JSON.NET cannot parse an object as an array.

For further clarification, this is what you're sending:

```json
{
    "assignees": [
        { ... assignee1 ... },
        { ... assignee2 ... },
        ...
    ]
}
```

However, it's the array that's expected, so it should look like this:

```json
[
    { ... assignee1 ... },
    { ... assignee2 ... },
    ...
]
```

All you need to do is change your current `JSON.stringify` line to this:

```js
JSON.stringify(assignmentPage.SelectedUsers)
```

---

An alternative option is to create a model class in your ASP.NET Core project and use that instead of a list of strings. Here's what that would look like:

```
public class AssignmentModel
{
    public List<UserViewModel> Assignees { get; set; }
}
```

The `Assignment` action would look like this:

```
public IActionResult Assignment(Guid id, [FromBody] AssignmentModel thisNameDoesNotMatter)
```